# Appending DOM elements non-blockingly with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom

I want to append 2000 table rows with asynchronous JavaScript. It takes about 3 seconds and all that time the UI controls are blocked inside the page. Can I append to the DOM without that blocking?

As you can see the checkbox in the demo can be clicked after 3-4 seconds only:

https://jsfiddle.net/zencd/xpvt214o/16545/

What's inside the demo:

```
function populateTable() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 4*1000; i++) {
    var tr = $('<tr></tr>');
    ...
    tr.appendTo(table);
  }
}
setTimeout(populateTable, 0); // async
```

Comment: append them to a tbody element and than append that tbody element to a table.

Answer (score 1):

https://jsfiddle.net/759L1c90/

The idea is to populate the table in chunks, then let the UI update in between chunks. This allows the user to interact with the checkbox and see the table populating, instead of staring at a blank page with an unresponsive UI.

You can fiddle with the variables to find an acceptable UX. This answer uses [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function), if you're not familiar with them I suggest you learn it because it's quite useful. The trade off here is that the table takes longer to populate but it's worth it.

EDIT: I recommend building the table as a string and inserting only once since it's fast, as the other answers do. However this method of async "chunk" loading is a good pattern to know.

```
var t1 = new Date().getTime();
var log = console.log;
var table = $('#the-table');
var rows = 4000
var columns = 10
var chunk = 100
var timeout = 50

async function populateTable() {
  let totalRows = rows
  while(totalRows > 0){
    await addChunk()
    totalRows -= chunk
  }
  log('table populated at ', (new Date().getTime() - t1), 'ms');
}

function addChunk(){
    return new Promise(resolve=>{
    setTimeout(()=>{
      for (var i = 0; i < chunk; i++) {
        var tr = $('<tr></tr>');
        for (var j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
          var td = $('<td></td>');
          td.text('' + i + '_' + j);
          td.appendTo(tr);
        }
        tr.appendTo(table);
        resolve()
      }
    },timeout)
  })
}

setTimeout(populateTable, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Start by using vanilla JS instead (quicker), and by inserting the HTML all at once, rather than inserting every row, td, and text individually thousands of times:

```
const t1 = new Date().getTime();
const log = console.log;
const table = document.querySelector('#the-table');
function populateTable() {
  const trStrings = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 4000; i++) {
    const tdValues = [];
    for (let j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
      tdValues.push(i + '_' + j);
    }
    trStrings.push('<tr><td>' + tdValues.join('</td><td>') + '</td></tr>');
  }
  table.innerHTML = trStrings.join('');
  log('table populated at ', (new Date().getTime() - t1), 'ms');
}
setTimeout(populateTable, 0);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/16614/

Stats:

(index):80 table populated at  79 ms

(index):80 table populated at  78 ms

(index):80 table populated at  77 ms

(index):80 table populated at  73 ms

(index):80 table populated at  81 ms

It's still "blocking" in a sense, which can still be resolved if desired, but it's orders of magnitudes faster, so the issue of blocking is less of a concern.

But this is really something that should be served via the server, if possible, rather than being parsed and rendered on-the-fly with Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, I was late. As a similar answer, I used vanilla JS, promise and functional programming to draw the table much quicker.

One key reason for non-blocking is that the TABLE should be created in memory. Insert the TR to this in memory TABLE. Finally, when the looping is done, insert the TABLE to DOM. Here is the code:

```
const generateTable = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        const table = document.createElement('table');
        const column = Array.from({ length: 4000}, (v, i) => i);
        const row = Array.from({ length: 10}, (v, i) => i);

        column.forEach((col, i) => {
            const tr = document.createElement('tr');

            row.forEach((r, j) => {
                const td = document.createElement('td');

                td.innerHTML = `${i}-${j}`;
                tr.appendChild(td);
            })

         table.appendChild(tr);
    })

    table.id = 'the-table';
    resolve(table);
  })
}

const t1 = new Date().getTime();
generateTable()
    .then(table => {
    document.body.appendChild(table);
    console.log('table populated at ', (new Date().getTime() - t1), 'ms');
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to load something fast, do not use jQuery, use plain JavaScript.
2. If you are interacting with the DOM, do it once not 44,000 times.
3. Create everything that needs to be inserted into a table by starting at its child element which is `<tbody>`. Once the contents of `<tbody>` has been appended within (4,000 rows + 40,000 cells), create a [**DocumentFragment**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment) and append the `<tbody>` to it.
4. At this point the browser has executed 44,002 statements in a span of @100ms as a Stack Snippet on SO or @60ms<sup>★</sup> as a [Plunk](http://run.plnkr.co/plunks/Xml2KqQMmPmWgHd7ZWK6/) on Plunker. ***But the browser has not even touched the DOM yet.***
5. Last statement to execute is to append the docFrag to the `<table>`. That is the one and only DOM interaction committed.
6. In the DOM, Appending a single `<tbody>` to a `<table>` only once is a walk in the park.
7. In the DOM, appending 4,000 `<tr>` and 40,000 `<td>` into a `<table>` is costly.
8. Notice the script is placed before the `</body>` end tag so blocking is not a concern.

<sup>★</sup> 1st test is @100ms, 2nd test is @80ms, 3rd test is @60ms

### Demo - Review this [Plunk](http://run.plnkr.co/plunks/Xml2KqQMmPmWgHd7ZWK6/) for a faster load

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>

  </head>

  <body>
   <label>UI<input type="checkbox"></label>
   <output id='msg'></output>
   <table id="table01" border="1"></table>
  <script>
   var t0 = new Date().getTime();
   var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
   var tb = document.createElement('tbody');

   for (let i = 0; i < 4000; i++) {
     const tr = document.createElement('tr');
     for (let j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        const td = document.createElement('td');
        td.textContent = `${i}_${j}`;
        tr.appendChild(td);
      }
      tb.appendChild(tr);
    }
    frag.appendChild(tb);
    document.getElementById('table01').appendChild(frag);
    var t1 = new Date().getTime();
    document.getElementById('msg').value = `time elapsed for insertion: ${t1 - t0}`;
   </script>
  </body>

</html>
```